# pygame error: video system not initialized even I initialized it

Tags: python, pygame

```
import sys
import pygame

def run_game():
   pygame.init()
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
   pygame.display.set_caption("Alien game")

while True:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          sys.exit()

   pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

I’m starting playing with the pygame module and I want to display a window but when I run the program I face this problem pygame error: video system not initalized even I have put pygame.init() in a function and I call it later in the program, I have tried to put pygame.init() after the importing statements but I face another problem in pygame.display.flip(),  the error say pygame.error: Display mode not set

Comment: Shouldn't your `while` be _in_ `run_game()` func? (Ie tab it)

Comment: You are calling `pygame.display.flip()` before `run_game()`, which initializes pygame

Answer (score 1):

it's due to indentations.
the main loop isn't in your `run_game` function, but in the main part of the code, because it miss an indent.
All of your `while` loop need 1 more indent.
Here you start your infinite loop before calling `run_game`, and so without initializing pygame.
Here is the correct code

```py
import sys
import pygame

def run_game():
   pygame.init()
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
   pygame.display.set_caption("Alien game")

    while True:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              sys.exit()

       pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```